# enabling/disabling checkbox according to some condition

Tags: apache-flex

I have a chechbox in a gridview. i need it disabled for some condition and enabled for other.
Problem is how to fetch check box id out side the grid.

Please help ....

Comment: Can you post some code?  Is this MXML or ActionScript?  What is the condition the checkbox is dependent on?  More context would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" xmlns:pw="http://intelligentpathways.com.au/Flex/v2">

    <mx:ArrayCollection id="ac">
        <mx:Object name="Alpha" enabled="{true}"/>
        <mx:Object name="Bravo" enabled="{true}"/>
        <mx:Object name="Charlie" enabled="{false}"/>
        <mx:Object name="Delta" enabled="{false}"/>
        <mx:Object name="Echo" enabled="{true}"/>
    </mx:ArrayCollection>

    <mx:Panel horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0" title="Renderer Demo">
        <mx:DataGrid width="500" height="300" dataProvider="{ac}">
            <mx:columns>
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Name" dataField="name"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Enabled?" dataField="enabled"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Checkbox">
                    <mx:itemRenderer>
                        <mx:Component>
                            <mx:Box paddingLeft="3">
                                <mx:CheckBox label="Foxtrot" enabled="{data.enabled}"/>
                            </mx:Box>
                        </mx:Component>
                    </mx:itemRenderer>
                </mx:DataGridColumn>
            </mx:columns>
        </mx:DataGrid>
    </mx:Panel>

</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

By giving you're check box an ID you should be able to reference it no matter what container objects it's it.

```
<mx:CheckBox id=myCheckbox ... />
```

can then be referenced in any script in that file like this:

```
private function toggleCheckBoxEnabled():void{
    if(some condition){
      myCheckBox.enabled = true;
    }else{
      myCheckBox.enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: can we give the ID of check box if it is inside the renderer ???
it is giving error

Comment: Assigning an ID inside of any looping code tends to break the concept of an ID, as they should be 100% unique, so it isn't good planning to put them in a renderer. I misunderstood that was what was happening since you said gridview I assumed a grid, when you meant a datagrid. I think sophistifunk has a decent answer for you. If his doesn't work you really need to post a code snippet so we can see what you are doing and what your intent is.